# How to use BitBlt in Python

Tags: python, windows, gdi

How would I go about using BitBlt in python? I know how to use PatBlt, but I was wondering how you use BitBlt. How would I put a image on the GDI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know how to use `PatBlt` then you are most of the way there.

`BitBlt` just transfers pixels from one DC to another. Often one DC has a bitmap selected into it and the other DC is the screen. It can be used to take screen shots, display pictures or do double buffering.

Let's say you have a bitmap loaded from `LoadImage` and you want to display it in `WM_PAINT`.

1. Call `BeginPaint` to get a DC for your window (the destination).
2. Call `CreateCompatibleDC` to create a source DC that is compatible with the destination.
3. Call `SelectObject` to select the bitmap (`HBITMAP`) into the source DC. You should store the return value so it can be restored during cleanup.
4. Call `BitBlt(destination DC, ..., source DC, ...., SRCCOPY)` to copy the bitmap pixels to the window.
5. Call `SelectObject` to restore the original value.
6. Call `DeleteDC` to destroy the source DC.
7. Call `EndPaint`.

Comment: I am sorry but, could please provide some of example? I cant seem to figure it out. @Anders

Answer (score 0):

## Hey Everyone!

I figured it out, and you can find the answer here:

```py
for i in range(100):
  BitBlt(desk, 1, 1, sw, sh, desk, 0, 0, SRCCOPY)
```